# Laravel button not is not submitting

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

Please let me know why my button is not working (add new post button)
Please find the code for the create.blade.php and PostsController.php and web.php

**create.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="/p" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        @csrf


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 offset-2">

            <div class="row">
                <h1>Add New Post</h1>
            </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label for="image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Post Image</label>

                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">

                            @error('image')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror

                        </div>

                        <div class="row pt-4">
                            <buttton class="btn btn-primary">Add New Post</buttton>
                        </div>

        </div>


    </div>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

when i try to press add new post nothing happens why is that ?

Comment: Add type submit to your button

Comment: Use instead `<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Post</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for submitting forms you should add the `submit` type to the input so you can simply do it like :
insead of :

```
<buttton class="btn btn-primary">Add New Post</buttton>
```

please put :

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add New Post">
```

Hope This Helps You